# why is the Arrayindex out of bound in the following code in java? I have checked the bounds but don't understand why/

Tags: java

`Arrayindex out of bounds` error is showing up and I have particularly no idea why it is hapening. I am trying create 2N tuple objects and trying to put them in a array of size 2N

```
Tuple[] minuteunit = new Tuple[2*N];
if(!intervals.isEmpty())
{
    for(i = 0; i < ((2*N)-1); i = 1+2)
    {
        minuteunit[i] = new Tuple(intervals.get(i).getBeginMinuteUnit(),"s");
        minuteunit[i+1] = new Tuple(intervals.get(i).getEndMinuteUnit(),"e");
    }
```

Comment: Presumably `N` has changed. Just put `if (i >= minuteunit.length) { System.out.println("Ooops!"); }` inside your loop and set a breakpoint on the System.out.println statement. Then you can look at the current state of your vars and find the problem.

Comment: your code doesn't say `i = i + 2`, it says `i = 1 + 2`

Comment: What does `intervals.get(i)` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is most likely the face you are using `i` in `intervals.get(i)`, because `i` is incrementing `+2`. I would imagine you have `N` values in `intervals` and therefore when `i >= (N/2)` you get an overflow.

Try this:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    minuteunit[2*i] = new Tuple(intervals.get(i).getBeginMinuteUnit(),"s");
    minuteunit[2*i+1] = new Tuple(intervals.get(i).getEndMinuteUnit(),"e");
}
```

Also, assuming intervals should contain `N` entries, you could update your `intervals.isEmpty()` check to:

```
if(intevals.size() == N)
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < ((2*N)-1); i = 1+2)
```

At each iteration i equals 3, so it never finishes. I think you want to add 2 at each iteration so use:

```
for(i = 0; i < ((2*N)-1); i = i+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your loop's termination condition `i<2*N-2`, otherwise the iteration of adding 2 will push `i` over the end of your array when `i` is `2*N-2` (which it wi eventually be).

btw, I assume that your iteration of `i=1+2` is a typo, and you have actually coded `i=i+2`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark here and guess that maybe `intervals.get(i)` is what's actually causing your problem here and not the array itself.  Ignoring what appears to be a typo in the increment, the condition for your loop seems to be fine, since if `i < 2*N - 1`, then `i + 1 < 2*N` and so there's no out of bound index *for the array*.  That leaves the `intervals.get(i)` method.